# Why are the android buttons freezing my app and not functioning?

Tags: android, back-button, slidingdrawer

I'm currently working on an app where a user can post logs to a project. However, it seems as if I have come across a problem and cannot seem to find the answer. The back button does not close the log activity after a user makes a post. Instead, it makes the app unresponsive; the logcat from such an instance is at the bottom. However, clicking "wait" instead of "force close" resumes the app, but the back button still does not work. Below is the layout of the activity. Each view in the viewflipper is a different log for the project with several edittexts to fill in info and a button to post to the log. Originally, this was laid out where the current posts were displayed below the post buttons in a listview. At that point, the back button had full functionality. However, a listview inside a scrollview doesn't work so well, so it had to be changed to the sliding drawer with a listview whose adapter is changed each time the user flips between the logs. This is the point where the back button functionality was lost. At first I thought I was doing something wrong in my onKeyDown method, but after trying to debug it, modify it, and even remove it, I found it never gets called. Because this started occurring after I changed to a sliding drawer, my conclusion is that it has something to do with the sliding drawer. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** After a thorough exploration of this problem, I have found that it is not just the back button that does this. The settings button and the search button both exhibit this behavior as well. The only button that exhibits correct functionality is the home button. However, functionality within the activity is not affected. I can still post, flip between the views, and view and edit posts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/iphonebg" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <!-- Header -->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <!-- Date -->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <!-- Tabs -->
    </TableRow>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/iphonebg" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" >

                    <!-- adding views to ViewFlipper -->
                    <!-- ScrollView 1 -->
                    <!-- ScrollView 2 -->
                    <!-- ScrollView 3 -->
                    <!-- ScrollView 4 -->
                    <!-- ScrollView 5 -->
                </ViewFlipper>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:content="@+id/anyPosts"
            android:handle="@+id/handle" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="35dip"
                android:background="@drawable/black_btn_bg"
                android:text="Drag or Tap to View Posts"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/anyPosts"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip" >
            </ListView>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </FrameLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

The extent of the code dealing with the sliding drawer, located in my onCreate method:

```
        final SlidingDrawer slide = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        final Button btnDownloads = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
        slide.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened() {
                btnDownloads.setText("Drag or Tap to Close Posts");
            }
        });

        slide.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed() {
                btnDownloads.setText("Drag or Tap to View Posts");
            }
        });
        slide.animateOpen();
```

The extent of the code dealing with the listview:

```
    ListView listToFill = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.anyPosts);
    listToFill.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
```

Logcat:

```
06-07 13:51:44.394: I/InputDispatcher(1464): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{40cd7758 token=HistoryRecord{40534788 uda.projectlogging/.Radio_Group}} - Window{40ae0a88 uda.projectlogging/uda.projectlogging.Radio_Group paused=false}.  10009.8ms since event, 10009.4ms since wait started
06-07 13:51:44.394: I/WindowManager(1464): Input event dispatching timed out sending to uda.projectlogging/uda.projectlogging.Radio_Group
06-07 13:51:44.444: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 23939 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.444: I/dalvikvm(23939): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.444: I/dalvikvm(23939): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.444: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1464 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.444: I/dalvikvm(1464): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.484: I/dalvikvm(1464): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.484: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1690 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.484: I/dalvikvm(1690): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.484: I/dalvikvm(1690): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.484: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1639 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.484: I/dalvikvm(1639): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/dalvikvm(1639): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1689 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/dalvikvm(1689): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/dalvikvm(1689): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1672 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/dalvikvm(1672): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/dalvikvm(1672): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1656 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.494: I/dalvikvm(1656): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.504: I/dalvikvm(1656): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.504: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1652 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.504: I/dalvikvm(1652): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1652): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1642 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1642): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1642): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1664 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1664): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1664): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1675 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1675): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1675): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1691 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1691): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1691): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1590 SIG: 3
06-07 13:51:44.514: I/dalvikvm(1590): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
06-07 13:51:44.524: I/dalvikvm(1590): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 13:51:44.734: D/dalvikvm(1464): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1754K, 33% free 9128K/13511K, external 6035K/6964K, paused 2ms+6ms
06-07 13:51:44.814: D/dalvikvm(1464): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31K, 33% free 9107K/13511K, external 6035K/6964K, paused 71ms
06-07 13:51:44.914: E/NetlinkEvent(1351): NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UDEV_LOG' not found
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464): ANR in uda.projectlogging, pid 23939 (uda.projectlogging/.Radio_Group)
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464): Load: 0.26 / 0.25 / 0.21
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464): CPU usage from 7340ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   0.9% 783/als_wq: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   0.8% 1464/system_server: 0.1% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):     0.5% 1489/ActivityManager: 0.1% user + 0.4% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):     0.2% 1543/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):     0.1% 1539/PowerManagerSer: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   0% 19639/com.svox.pico: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 56 minor
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):     0% 19639/com.svox.pico: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   0.4% 288/tegra_spi.1: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   0.4% 19564/com.android.vending: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):     0.2% 19566/HeapWorker: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   0% 1358/battd: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   0.1% 21254/com.motorola.android.datamanager: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):     0.1% 21255/HeapWorker: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464): 7.9% TOTAL: 1.3% user + 2% kernel + 0.1% iowait + 4.3% softirq
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464): CPU usage from 420ms to 934ms later with 99% awake:
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):   7.6% 1464/system_server: 1.9% user + 5.7% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464):     3.8% 1543/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 3.8% kernel
06-07 13:51:45.364: E/ActivityManager(1464): 3.9% TOTAL: 1.9% user + 1.9% kernel
```

When the post button is clicked:

```
postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getApplicationContext(), R.anim.image_click));
                data = new JSONObject();
                if (description.equals("")) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please Enter a Description",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else if (delayStart == null) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please Set Delay Duration",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    try {
                        data.put("COMMENT", description);
                        data.put("DELAYSTART",
                                delayStart.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                                        + delayStart.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                        data.put("DELAYEND", delayEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                                + ":" + delayEnd.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                        postEntry();
                        description = "";
                        delayHours = 0;
                        delayMinutes = 0;
                        delayStart = null;
                        delayEnd = null;
                        delay.setText("");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Posting the Entry:

```
public void postEntry() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog1.setCancelable(true);
    dialog1.setMessage("Loading...");

    dialog1.show();

    final Thread background1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            try {
                String type1 = "0";
                switch (current) {
                case 0:
                    type1 = "1";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    type1 = "4";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    type1 = "3";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    type1 = "6";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    type1 = "5";
                    break;
                }
                if (helperMethods.isOnline(currentActivity)) {
                    if (failedUploads)
                        doFailedUploads();
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                            "http://www.constructiononline.com/service/",
                            "OSLPost");
                    PropertyInfo num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                    num1.setName("userEmail");
                    num1.setValue(settings.getString("EMAIL", ""));
                    request.addProperty(num1);

                    num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                    num1.setName("prj_id");
                    num1.setValue(projectInfo.getID());
                    request.addProperty(num1);

                    num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                    num1.setName("entryDate");
                    num1.setValue(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                    request.addProperty(num1);

                    num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                    num1.setName("type");
                    num1.setValue(type1);
                    request.addProperty(num1);

                    num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                    num1.setName("data");
                    num1.setValue(data.toString());
                    request.addProperty(num1);

                    num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                    num1.setName("delete");
                    num1.setValue("false");
                    request.addProperty(num1);

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                            URL);

                    androidHttpTransport
                            .call("http://www.constructiononline.com/service/OSLPost",
                                    envelope);

                    Log.e("Response from Post", envelope.getResponse()
                            .toString());

                    updatePostList(false);
                } else {
                    addFailedUploads(settings.getString("EMAIL", ""),
                            projectInfo.getID(), month + "/" + day + "/"
                                    + year, type1, data.toString());
                    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
                    j.put("LOG_OBJECT", data);
                    j.put("TYPE", type1);
                    j.put("DATE", month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String created = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/"
                            + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/"
                            + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "
                            + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " "
                            + (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 ? "AM" : "PM");
                    j.put("CREATED", created);
                    JSONObject creatorTemp = new JSONObject();
                    creatorTemp.put("ID", "0");
                    creatorTemp.put("NAME", " ");
                    creatorTemp.put("COMPANY", " ");
                    creatorTemp.put("ICON", "NULL");
                    j.put("CREATOR", creatorTemp);
                    j.put("ID", "0");
                    switch (current) {
                    case 0:
                        weatherEntries.put(j);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        workEntries.put(j);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        visitorEntries.put(j);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        deliveryEntries.put(j);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        noteEntries.put(j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (dialog1 != null && dialog1.isShowing()) {
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                }

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                String stacktrace = sw.toString();

                addOnlineErrorLogEntry(e.getMessage(), stacktrace);
                if (dialog1 != null && dialog1.isShowing()) {
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                e.getMessage() + " in setupProjects",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            }

        }
    });

    // start the background thread
    background1.start();
}
```

Updating the Post List:

```
private void updatePostList(final boolean getAll) {
    if (!helperMethods.isOnline(currentActivity)) {
        return;
    }

    final ProgressDialog dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog1.setCancelable(true);
    dialog1.setMessage("Loading...");

    dialog1.show();

    final Thread background1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            try {
                if (failedUploads)
                    doFailedUploads();
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                        "http://www.constructiononline.com/service/",
                        "OSLGet");
                PropertyInfo num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                num1.setName("userEmail");
                num1.setValue(settings.getString("EMAIL", ""));
                request.addProperty(num1);

                num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                num1.setName("prj_id");
                num1.setValue(projectInfo.getID());
                request.addProperty(num1);

                num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                num1.setName("startDate");
                num1.setValue("");
                if (!getAll) {
                    num1.setValue(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                }
                request.addProperty(num1);

                num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                num1.setName("endDate");
                num1.setValue("");
                request.addProperty(num1);

                num1 = new PropertyInfo();
                num1.setName("type");
                num1.setValue("");
                if (!getAll) {
                    switch (current) {
                    case 0:
                        num1.setValue("1");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        num1.setValue("4");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        num1.setValue("3");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        num1.setValue("6");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        num1.setValue("5");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                request.addProperty(num1);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                        URL);

                androidHttpTransport.call(
                        "http://www.constructiononline.com/service/OSLGet",
                        envelope);

                Log.e("response", envelope.getResponse().toString());
                JSONObject temp = new JSONObject(envelope.getResponse()
                        .toString());
                JSONArray entries = temp.getJSONArray("ENTRIES");
                if (getAll) {
                    weatherEntries = new JSONArray();
                    workEntries = new JSONArray();
                    visitorEntries = new JSONArray();
                    deliveryEntries = new JSONArray();
                    noteEntries = new JSONArray();
                }
                switch (current) {
                case 0:
                    weatherEntries = new JSONArray();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    workEntries = new JSONArray();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    visitorEntries = new JSONArray();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    deliveryEntries = new JSONArray();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    noteEntries = new JSONArray();
                    break;
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < entries.length(); x++) {
                    switch (entries.getJSONObject(x).getInt("TYPE")) {
                    case 1:
                        weatherEntries.put(entries.getJSONObject(x));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        visitorEntries.put(entries.getJSONObject(x));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        workEntries.put(entries.getJSONObject(x));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        noteEntries.put(entries.getJSONObject(x));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        deliveryEntries.put(entries.getJSONObject(x));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (getAll) {
                            setupWeatherLog();
                        } else {
                            getPosts();
                        }
                    }

                });
                if (dialog1 != null && dialog1.isShowing()) {
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                }

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                String stacktrace = sw.toString();

                addOnlineErrorLogEntry(e.getMessage(), stacktrace);
                if (dialog1 != null && dialog1.isShowing()) {
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                e.getMessage() + " in setupProjects",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            }

            if (dialog1 != null && dialog1.isShowing()) {
                dialog1.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });

    // start the background thread
    background1.start();
}
```

Populating the listview:

```
private void getPosts() {

    JSONArray entriesToShow = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray postsToLoad = null;
    switch (current) {
    case 0:
        postsToLoad = weatherEntries;
        break;
    case 1:
        postsToLoad = workEntries;
        break;
    case 2:
        postsToLoad = visitorEntries;
        break;
    case 3:
        postsToLoad = deliveryEntries;
        break;
    case 4:
        postsToLoad = noteEntries;
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < postsToLoad.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject temp = postsToLoad.getJSONObject(i);
            String[] tempDay = temp.getString("DATE").split("/");
            if (Integer.parseInt(tempDay[0]) == month
                    && Integer.parseInt(tempDay[1]) == day
                    && Integer.parseInt(tempDay[2]) == year) {
                entriesToShow.put(temp);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    BaseAdapter listViewAdapter;
    switch (current) {
    case 0:
        listViewAdapter = new WeatherDeliveryVisitLazyAdapter(
                currentActivity, entriesToShow, current);
        break;
    case 1:
        listViewAdapter = new WorkLogPostLazyAdapter(currentActivity,
                entriesToShow);
        break;
    case 2:
        listViewAdapter = new WeatherDeliveryVisitLazyAdapter(
                currentActivity, entriesToShow, current);
        break;
    case 3:
        listViewAdapter = new WeatherDeliveryVisitLazyAdapter(
                currentActivity, entriesToShow, current);
        break;
    case 4:
        listViewAdapter = new ProjectNotePostLazyAdapter(currentActivity,
                entriesToShow);
        break;
    default:
        listViewAdapter = new ProjectNotePostLazyAdapter(currentActivity,
                entriesToShow);
    }

    if (listViewAdapter == null || listViewAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No Posts to Display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    ListView listToFill = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.anyPosts);
    listToFill.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

}
```

That is everything it does when the post button is clicked in any log. If I have interpreted this correctly, when all the progress dialogs have cleared the screen, the background threads have ended, and the only thing that gets run on the ui thread, beyond the toasts in case of errors or incomplete information, is setting up the listview, which does get completed. When I pull open the drawer, it displays the correct list of posts.

**EDIT** I have found that if I comment out the progress dialog in the updatePostList method, it works just fine. So new question: Why in the world is that the solution?

**Final Edit** I figured it out. That progress dialog was getting launched from a background thread. Modified the postEntry method so it calls updatePostList on the UI thread so the progress dialog gets created on the UI thread, and it works. Yay.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you might be starting some long-running process from the main thread. Doing something like writing to a file, updating a database or performing network I/O on the main thread will cause it to become unresponsive. You should use a `Service` or an `AsyncTask` when performing operations like this.

Here are some articles that might be useful to you:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Comment: I was looking into that, but the thing is, I have one lengthy task, getting the project log entries from the server, which is handled in a background thread, and is completed before I hit the back button. There are no tasks running on the UI thread before I click the back button either (that I am aware of).

Comment: I've posted everything that gets executed when a post button is clicked.

Comment: I've found a solution. Do you have any input on why that is the solution?

Comment: what was you solution? can you please post it here? I am also facing the same problem